# How do I get a partial view to pass related objects to post method in .NET MVC?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

I have a partial view in a modal that takes a viewmodel like so:

```
public class AssetOtherEventViewModel
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;

    public Asset Asset { get; set; }

    public ICollection<AssetEvent> OtherEvents { get; set; }
}
```

This is the view:

```
@model XXXXXXX.ViewModels.AssetOtherEventViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveOtherEvents", "AssetEvent", null))
{
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Asset)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Date)

        @foreach (GrindrodDataCapture.Models.AssetEvent assetEvent in Model.OtherEvents)
        {
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.Label(assetEvent.EventType.Name)
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => assetEvent.Hours, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => assetEvent.Hours, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        }
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

When I land on the public `ActionResult SaveOtherEvents(AssetOtherEventViewModel vm)` method the `Asset` and `OtherEvents` properties are null.

Does anyone know how to better approach this or fix it?

Comment: Can you the HttpGet method and Asset class and AssetEvent class?

Comment: Why razor-pages tag is added

Comment: try using this                                                                                                             @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveOtherEvents", "AssetEvent", FormMethod.Post))

Comment: Asset is a child class. That issue is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29607511/mvc-model-child-object-null-on-http-post). OtherEvents is a collection. Binding to a collection is described in probably 100 questions here, but [this](https://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/) is the link many refer to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by indexing the object properties I needed. That way they came through to the post controller.

```
@model XXXXXXXX.ViewModels.AssetOtherEventViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveOtherEvents", "AssetEvent", null))
{
<div class="form-horizontal">
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AssetID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Date)
    <fieldset>

        <div id="EditorRows">
            @for (var i = 0; i < Model.OtherEvents.Count; i++)
            {

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.Label(Model.OtherEvents[i].EventType.Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.OtherEvents[i].Hours, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>
            </div>


                @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.OtherEvents[i].EventType_ID)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.OtherEvents[i].ID)

            }
        </div>
    </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [BeginCollectionItem](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/) to receive complex model on post
On you main page
do some thing like this

```
<fieldset>
        <legend>Order Items</legend>
        <div data-demo-ajax="list-order-items">
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Items)
        </div>
        <p>
            <a href="#" data-demo-ajax="add-order-item" data-demo-ajax-url="@Url.Action(MVC.Demo.OrderItem())">Add Order Item</a>
        </p>
    </fieldset>
```

For child collection item

```
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Items"))
{
    //Your child element
}
```

You may find many example if you search begincollectionitem one such is [here](https://github.com/danludwig/BeginCollectionItem/tree/master/BeginCollectionItem.Mvc3Demo) from project page.

Comment: Thanks but this assembly didn't work for me. The EditorTemplate it installed caused bugs out the box and so I uninstalled it and found another way

Comment: you don't necessarily need to use editor template. you may use normal html helper @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Items")) is the key here. BTW editor template shouldn't  be causing any issue

Comment: https://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/

Comment: The editortemplate was causing an error when named Collection.cshtml and throwing an error for a null Model.  After renaming the application could build again. Thanks for the advice but as I said I found a different way. Thanks